# Simil Bernoulli inequality for induction

Tags: number-theory, induction

> Prove that $(1+x)^n \ge nx, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall x>-1 $

My work:

If $-1<x \le 0$ it's trivial because $RHS \le 0$ and $LHS \ge 0$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Start with the induction. If $n=0$ we have $1>0$, so suppose true for all $m<n+1$ and proof for $m=n+1$:

$$(1+x)^{(n+1)}=(1+x)(1+x)^n \ge (1+x)nx$$

So i have to proof that $(1+x)nx \ge (n+1)x$ that it means that

$$nx+nx^2 \ge nx+x \longrightarrow nx \ge 1$$

but this is not even true (e.g. $n=1,x=10^{-2}$).

Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: The usual form of Bernoulli is $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$

Comment: @AnginaSeng yes. But I can't use Bernoulli inequality to prove this. I have to do it for induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x \geq 0$. If you are keen on using induction prove the stronger inequality $(1+x)^{n} \geq 1+nx$. Here induction works fine and the required inequality follows from this.

[$(1+x)(1+nx) =1+x+nx+nx^{2} \geq 1+(n+1)x$].

Comment: Thanks, but the purpose of the exercise is to use the induction principle. I must not use the Bernoulli inequality.

Comment: @Skills You did not read my answer correctly. I did not use Bernoulli's inequality. I used induction. But I use a small trick to change the given inequality to something stronger. The original inequality does not follow directly by induction as you have noticed.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read after editing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets prove a stronger inequality, $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx > nx$.

We want to show  that $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$ for all natural numbers $n$ and for all $x>-1$.

Since $x>-1$, then $x+1>0$, so $(x+1)^n>0$. That handles the condition that $x>-1$.

Now, we want to induct on $n$.

Base cases, $n=0$ and $n=1$: $$(1+x)^0=1\geq 1+0\cdot x=1$$  $$(1+x)^1=1+x\geq 1+ 1\cdot x =1+x$$ Both are true, so our base cases are complete.

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx $ for some natural number $n$. We wish to show that this is true for $n+1$.

$$\begin{align}(1+x)^{n+1}&=(1+x)(1+x)^n\\&\geq(1+x)(1+nx)\\&=1+(n+1)x+nx^2\\&\geq 1+(n+1)x\end{align} $$

Since we have now shown that for all natural numbers $n$, $$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx $$ with equality at $n=0,n=1$, then it follows that $$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx > nx\geq 0\geq -n$$ and we are done by induction.